# Self-intersecting colored polyline

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, coloring

A few days ago I got a problem like this at a math Olympiad. I have some ideas, but I can't seem to complete the proof.

> Tim draws polylines, and then colors their sides as follows: vertical lines drawn from top to bottom are blue; vertical lines drawn from bottom to top are purple; horizontal lines drawn from left to right are orange; horizontal lines drawn from right to left are red; and oblique lines are green. One of Tim's drawings shows a closed polyline with exactly one orange side among any two adjacent sides. Is it true that this polyline is self-intersecting?

What do I know about the problem:

1. the number of links is even (each non-orange link is connected to the right with an orange link).
2. for any segment two adjacent segments lie on the same line or in different half-planes

I would like a rigorous proof of this fact, so that I can learn how to solve similar problems in the future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Until January 11, 2021 - registration and qualifying stage of the St. Petersburg State University 2020/2021 academic year" https://olympiada.spbu.ru/